# Calculate length of time between two times in AM/PM

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, difference

I have three `DrowDownLists`  for selecting start time and another three for selecting end time. I need an asp.net program which will give duration between two time and after i entered start time then end time should be greater than start time. First `DrowDownList` contains 1 to 12 hours and second contains 0 to 59 minutes and third one is for selecting `am/pm`.

[image]

I don't know where to start in codebehind.

Comment: What Soner wants to say is: you haven't asked a question so far. You have given us a very brief specification book.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a few times..

Comment: Its my first question .So whts wrong in my question?

Answer (score 1):

You could first turn your strings into TimeSpan, try out TimeSpan.Parse:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx

With two TimeSpan objects, you will be able to calculate durations without having to worry on how to do it. To get the duration between two timespans, try out TimeSpan.Subtract:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx

hope this helps!